# Find differences between column names in two csv files?

Tags: python, csv, awk

I have two csv files with their first rows being the names of the columns.
I would like to `diff` their sets of column names, i.e. to find out

- whether the two files have the same set of column names (the order of the columns doesn't matter), and
- if they don't, what column names in one file but not in the other..

Is it possible to do that using `awk`, or other text processing utilities in Linux?
Or is it better to use Python?

e.g. suppose one file looks like

```
col2,col1,col3
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

and the other file looks like

```
col3,col2,col4
2,3,4
5,6,7
```

Then the column name in the first file but not in the second is `col1`, and the one in the second but not in the first is `col4`.

Comment: Are you asking people familiar with awk and Python _which one_ is best to use here, or are you asking _how_ to do it in either language?

Comment: I would like to know how to do in both, and then I will know which way is best to use here.

Answer (score 3):

In Python, first save the header rows for each file with `csv.reader`:

```
import csv
with open('one.csv', newline='') as f1, open('two.csv', newline='') as f2:
    one = set(next(csv.reader(f1)))
    two = set(next(csv.reader(f2)))
```

Then you can use `set` operations.

Whether they are the same:

```
one == two
```

Columns that `two` has but `one` does not:

```
two - one
```

Columns that `one` has but `two` does not:

```
one - two
```

For fun, columns that both files have:

```
one & two
```

And all available columns, in either file:

```
one | two
```

Answer (score 2):

If you put this in a.awk

```
BEGIN {
    FS = ","
}
FNR == 1 && NR == 1 {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) 
        a[$i] = 1
    notA = "Not in " FILENAME ":"
}
FNR == 1 && NR != 1 {
    notB = "Not in " FILENAME ":"
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if (!a[$i]) 
            notA = notA " " $i
        b[$i] = 1
    }
    for (i in a) {
        if (!b[i]) 
           notB = notB " " i
    }
    print notA
    print notB
}
```

After running

```
awk -f a.awk foo.txt foo1.txt
```

You will get output

```
Not in foo.txt: col4
Not in foo1.txt: col1
```

Answer (score 1):

bash and tools

only in file1

```
$ comm -23 <(sed 1q file1 | tr , "\n" | sort) <(sed 1q file2 | tr , "\n" | sort)
col1
```

only in file2

```
$ comm -13 <(sed 1q file1 | tr , "\n" | sort) <(sed 1q file2 | tr , "\n" | sort)
col4
```